# ASP.NET vb oracle database Date input error

Tags: asp.net, oracle

Im using following code to input data into orcale database via asp.net web application (vb).

```
Public Sub SaveRaidDetails()
                lblStatus.Text = ""
                Dim dt2 As DataTable = CType(ViewState("dt1"), DataTable)
                Dim er As Boolean = False
                Dim dtRaidDate As Date
                If dt2.Rows.Count > 0 Then
                    Try
                        dtRaidDate = Convert.ToDateTime(txtRaidDate.Text)
                    Catch ex As Exception
                        er = True
                    End Try
                    If er = False Then
                        lblDateEr.Visible = False
                        Dim intDisID, intMktSeq, intAgID As Integer
                        Dim dblFine As Double
                        If ddlDistributor.SelectedValue = "" Then
                            intDisID = 0
                        Else
                            intDisID = ddlDistributor.SelectedValue
                        End If
                        If ddlMarkets.SelectedValue = "" Then
                            intMktSeq = 0
                        Else
                            intMktSeq = ddlMarkets.SelectedValue
                        End If
                        If ddlAgency.SelectedValue = "" Then
                            intAgID = 0
                        Else
                            intAgID = ddlAgency.SelectedValue
                        End If
                        If txtFine.Text = "" Then
                            dblFine = 0
                        Else
                            dblFine = Convert.ToDouble((txtFine.Text))
                        End If
                        Dim intUserSeq As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(Session("UserSeq"))
                        Dim ret As Boolean
                        Dim rd1 As New RIMS_DATA.Raids
                        ret = rd1.AddRaid(dtRaidDate, txtCo.Text, txtCa.Text, intDisID, Convert.ToInt32(ddlRegion.SelectedValue), intAgID, intMktSeq, txtTrader.Text, txtTraderAdd.Text, dblFine, txtRemarks.Text, intUserSeq)
                        If ret = True Then
                            Dim intRaidID As Integer = rd1.ReadLastRaid()
                            Dim dtBatchDt As Date
                            For Each dr As DataRow In dt2.Rows
                                Try
                                    dtBatchDt = Convert.ToDateTime(dr("BDt"))
                                Catch ex As Exception
                                    dtBatchDt = Convert.ToDateTime("01/01/2000")
                                End Try
                                ret = rd1.AddRaid2(intRaidID, Convert.ToInt32(dr("BID")), Convert.ToInt32(dr("Qty")), dr("BCd"), dtBatchDt)
                            Next
                            ClearForm(1)
                            lblStatus.Text = "Record inserted successfully !"
                        lblDateEr.Visible = True
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Else
            lblStatus.Text = "Please enter the raid details !"
        End If
```

But the issue is in the Orcle database the date is saved in wrong format like this.. 20/07/0001 . But the date in the text box which i pass to variable is 2015/07/1. I use date time picker to input date to text box. how can i fix this problem.
    Is this enough for answer

Comment: can you put the code where the date is sent to the database?